# Is it possible to have an HTML slider's initial value depend on a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very inexperienced with programming (which certainly shows) and I've come across a particular problem trying to code an application on a website. Specifically, the user inputs a sequence of numbers which are stored in a decision table, which are eventually revisited. Numbers are input via a slider, and I'd like for the "revisit your decision" slider to start on the value that had been previously recorded.

Effectively, suppose the initial numerical input is stored as a variable "start". The code I have currently is: (Note, I'm not sure exactly what's relevant, so I'm over-pasting instead of under-pasting. For those more knowledgeable, feel free to cut it down substantially to a minimum working example.)

HTML:

```
<br>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">
<style>
.responsive {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.slidecontainer {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 25%;
    width: 75%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #ff6347;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 80%;  /* <-- Problem was here when width is 100% */
    height: 15px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.sliderticks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.sliderticks p {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20 0;
}

</style>

Use the slider to input a new value for x below:

<div class="slidecontainer" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><table>  <tbody><tr><td></td><td style="text-align:center;"><h3><br><b>Value 1</b>: <span id="demo"></span></h3><h3><b>10-Value 1</b>: <span id="demo2"></span></h3> </td> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-right: 10px;">Slider 0</td><td style="min-width: 700px;">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="startvalue" class="slider" id="myRange" step="0.25"></td><td style="padding-left: 10px;">Slider 10</td></tr>  
  <tr><td></td><td><div class="sliderticks">
    <p>0</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
   <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
   <p>10</p></div></td><td></td></tr> 
  
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

And I have the JS code:

```
start=getValue('decisions', 'PlayerNr='+ playerNr +' and period='+period, 'amount'); //There is code inside the parentheses that grabs this value from a table
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
var output3 = document.getElementById("startvalue");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
output2.innerHTML = 10-slider.value;
output3.innerHTML = b1;
b1=start;

slider.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value; // display value A in HTML
b1=this.value; // value A
b2=10-(b1); // value B
output2.innerHTML = b2; // display value B in HTML
revisit=b1;
record('revisit',revisit);
};
```

I'm sorry again that I'm sure there's a lot of useless info there!! I've tried everything I can think of in terms of switching out the `value="startvalue"` with pretty much everything I can think of ("b1", "start", etc.) but clearly nothing has worked.

Let me know if anything (besides the spaghetti code itself, with all likelihood) isn't clear and I can try to clarify! )(I can try to clarify the code too, but again, very scared to break it haha).

I have also copied it over to codepen (a la @ouchane.exe's suggestion!) and it is here: https://codepen.io/AndrewCEcon/pen/MWJQEmg

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hi , function getValue() is not defined , make pen in codepen maybe i can help :)

Comment: Hi ouchane.exe, thank you so much!! I added the code that I have in the web application, though I fear it might not help much in this context. (The website I'm using is basically for surveys and psych/econ experiments. The participants will have already input an amount, which has been saved in a sql table (maybe? I'm honestly not sure haha) which is saved as the 'amount' variable.) Again, I'm so sorry if that doesn't really help much, but let me know and I can try to fix it more! And I'm so sorry about my incompetence!! haha

Comment: yeah i have a lot of points may can helping you to improve your code

1 - use document.querySelector and pass name of id or class using (# or .) instead of  getElementById
2 - in declaration use var or let better than nothing 
3 - if you want to change value of input or any element use .value = 
i hope that helping you in your problem

Comment: That I dont doubt! Also, Im sorry, I just realized you meant use the website codepen haha. The link is https://codepen.io/AndrewCEcon/pen/MWJQEmg and I will add it to the body of the question above too! And thank you for the tips--Ill go through and try them ASAP!!

Comment: I believe you should be able to simply say `sliderElement.value = "50";` You should be able to replace `50` with any number you want. Or am I missing something? Here's an article that describes exactly what you're looking for: (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_range_value.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to simplify it as much as possible to make the mechanism clear to you.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Start value:</label>
<span id="startvalue"> 5 </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<label>Volume value:</label><span id="val"></span>
<div>
<input type="range" id="vol" name="volume" min="0" max="10">
</div>

<script>

slider = document.getElementById("vol");
sliderval  = document.getElementById("val"); 
function slider_init(){
   startvalue = document.getElementById("startvalue");
   slider.value = startvalue.innerHTML;   
   sliderval.innerHTML  = slider.value;
}
function slider_set(){
    sliderval.innerHTML  = slider.value;    
}
slider.addEventListener('input', slider_set);

</script>

<script>slider_init()</script>
```

or much simple:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Start value:</label>
<span id="startvalue"> 5 </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<label>Volume value:</label><span id="val"></span>
<div>
<input type="range" id="vol" name="volume" min="0" max="10">
</div>

<script>

//setting initial value of volume
slider = document.getElementById("vol");
sliderval  = document.getElementById("val"); 
startvalue = document.getElementById("startvalue");
slider.value = startvalue.innerHTML;   
sliderval.innerHTML  = slider.value;
   
//the function called by the EventListener (see below)
function slider_set(){
    sliderval.innerHTML  = slider.value;    
}
//when the input range "slider" changes  , slider_set is called
slider.addEventListener('input', slider_set);

</script>
```

Comment: Ooh, thank you for the answer (and hugely simplified code!) I think that works, but I just want to check before accepting: If I have a value that's defined in the Javascript code (let's say it's a variable called "test" (without the quotes)) and it equals a value between 0 and 10, can I have the start value id call that value? And if so, how? (Sorry again for my ignorance!) Thank you!!

Comment: In theory you can get and set anything  in the HTML. 
`startvalue.innerHTML = test.innerHTML`  or  `startvalue.value = test.value`  if the elements have 'value' attributes.  To set directly the  initial value of the slider to 5  use: `<input type="range" min=0 max=10 value=5>`

Comment: I think thats working!! Thank you so much!!